# minitest assert_select with capybara click_link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, minitest

How can I achieve checking presence of my link and then clicking on it? I tried the following:

```
  assert_select "a", "show/hide comments"
  click_link('show/hide comments')
```

I am using minitest, capybara, and the 'minitest-rails-capybara' gem. I have added the following include statements in my integration test:

```
include Capybara::DSL
include Capybara::Assertions
```

I get the following error:

```
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["show/hide comments"]  
MethodError:         NoMethodError: undefined method `failure_message' for Capybara::Helpers:Module
            test/integration/user_flow_test.rb:215:in `block in <class:UserFlowTest>'
```

Can I use both minitest's assert link and capybara's click_link?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, they work well together. What is the line `215` that is giving this error?

Comment: assert_select "a", "show/hide comments" I also noticed something before the error message: Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["show/hide comments"]  perhaps it thinks it's a capybara command and not minitest

Comment: Well, I've never actually used it this way. What I do is use capybara with e.g. `assert page.has_link? 'show/hide comments'`

Comment: @Iceman When using the minitest-capybara gem (identified by the include Capybara::Assertions) the assert could be written as `assert_link 'show/hide comments'` which does the same as your usage but with a better error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly there is no need to assert on the presence of an element before clicking it since `click_link` will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the link to appear on the page and then click it. If the link doesn't appear in that time it will raise an error, so asserting on its presence is superfluous.

The error you're getting is because minitest-capybara isn't compatible with Capybara 2.9+ - https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-capybara/pull/17 - and the fact that `assert_select` doesn't take 2 strings as parameters. It just takes the id, name, or label text of a select element.  So I'm guessing that's not actually the method you mean to be calling.

Comment: ok so I guess it's a bug thanks. As for assert_select according to the examples here http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select , you can pass two strings  ex: assert_select "title", "Welcome"

Comment: I am using assert_select since  click_link('show/hide comments') returns false and I wanted to debug but as you say it's superfluous.

Comment: @Ayrad thats the ActionController assertions - not minitest-capybara which is what you're using by including Capybara::Assertions - https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/assertions.rb#L171  - which takes the same parameters as Capybaras `has_select?`

Comment: @Ayrad don't forget to accept the answer (check mark) , so your question gets marked as answered,  if you understand the issue you're having now.

Comment: Aaaah the minitest-capybara gem overrides the rails included assert_select that comes with ActionController.

Comment: @Ayrad You can't use the ActionController::Assertions version of assert_select with Capybara in integration tests, they're not compatible since the rails assertions know nothing about the content loaded by Capybara.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136278/discussion-between-ayrad-and-thomas-walpole).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the previous answer:

Wrong:

```
assert_select "a", "show/hide comments"
```

Correct:

```
assert_select "a", text: "show/hide comments"
```